# Using a nested IFNULL to check tables along a mutually exclusive path?

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a field that may be in three different tables. The first table is an archive; although the archive is *supposed* to be updated as fields change, there is a non-zero possibility that this won't happen. As such, I would like to search the other two tables, in which the field is mutually exclusive (purged after joined from the second to the third table).

In my final select statement after using outer join on these tables together, I am imagining to solve this issue by implementing a select statement like so:

```
SELECT Field IFNULL(Table2, IFNULL(Table3, Table1))
```

The purpose for the second IFNULL being that if for some reason it wasn't in either due to error, the archive would possibly have the information (indicative of an issue).

Is there a more elegant solution to this problem that I am missing? I am relatively new to SQL and as such am not extremely familiar with the best practices. I think this function would not be very resource intensive due to already joining Table's 1 2 and 3, but I am not positive.

This field also is used to join the tables together, and if it is not in that table, a record will not exist on that table by my query criteria. My plan is to use this for a few different fields.

This will eventually be in a parameterized prepared statement used to implement search functionality on a front-end.

Comment: What field is used to join the tables? If it takes an outer join that is a fairly costly operation,

Comment: It is a left outer join on multiple fields, this field specifically being used to join them. A record won't exist on those tables if this field doesn't show up.

My original thought was to actually use this on a few fields, too, with the same constraints: without this field existing, the record will not exist either, and thus will render it null.

Comment: The ifnull is not that expensive if you are already using the outer join. It also makes it clear what you are doing, overall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`COALESCE()` is a bit more elegant than nested `IFNULL()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Table2.field, Table3.field, Table1.field) as Field
```

This is probably the best approach, assuming that `field` is never `NULL`.  If that is a valid value, then the logic might be a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you, I had actually completely forgotten about COALESCE and it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Is this function also about as resource intensive as IFNULL?

Comment: CPU cost is nothing compared to I/O and large memory accesses. Check the access plan if you care about performance